# Rewrite URL dont get values and error 404

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**My Htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&title=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2-%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**I have in php urls as this :**

```
index.php?id=34234&title=Hello_World&name=Mike
```

**In the link i put this :**

```
<a href="index.php?id=34234&title=Hello_World&name=Mike">TEST</a>
```

**And i try get this url**

```
http://www.test.com/34234/hello_world/mike
```

But all time give error as 404 error and i don´t know which it´s the solution for this, Thank´s in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Your original URL has 3 path segments while your rule accepts only two. You need to fix your regex patterns

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&title=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php.php?id=$1&title=$2&name=$3 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don´t understand but don´tworks i call url as this <a href="index.php?id=3333&title=holalala&name=2343434">TEST 2</a> or <a href="32342/Hello_World/Mike">TEST 3</a> ??? RewriteBase it´s test i forget tell

Comment: @Man try clearing your browser cache. I editing the code a few minutes after posting the answer. Did you try the updated version?

Comment: If your htaccess and php files are in `test` folder , then the RewriteBase should be `RewriteBase /test/`

Comment: Yes and other question why if i put links as this index.php?id=34234&title=Hello_World&name=Mike, never show urls friendly i need always use links as /34234/hello_world/mike, thank´s

Comment: @Man The rule does exactly what you are saying. Try clearing your browser cache. Make sure these rules are at the top of your htaccess file .

Comment: If i put this, don´t works <a href="index.php?id=333&title=ok&name=Mike">Test</a>